# Is the selections "@section Scripts & @Scripts.Render" is only for MVC not for Html page? Is we use to embed jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, frontend

Well i think razor views are only in MVC so we can only use these selections scripts in mvc only .. But why we use  `@section Scripts` & `@Scripts.Render` .. is we use with jQuery. Are we only supposed to use them in MVC Views not in a simple HTML Page or with JSON only?

```
**@section Scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}**
```

Comment: Its not related to jQuery. Its razer syntax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript, it's a Razor statement to locate code within your Layout.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, it has to do with Microsoft ASP.NET MVC. It allows a page to define a section that is rendered outside of the page in the layout file.

Comment: @Webbanditten  So, its mean the views , in which its included will call a razor view and to embed js code in view we write this.?

Comment: Read the docs. Provided.

Comment: 1. add a section to your _layout 2. in your view define an `@section` which will be rendered at the location of the section in your _layout.  Any more is too much for a 1-liner summary which is all you can get here.  You have the docs link and an SO answer to read up on.